# Форма отправки - не могу понять почему форма не видит запрос $.post('api.php' (ответ на сервер не приходит)

Tags: javascript, php, html5

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];`введите сюда код`
$email = $_POST['email'];

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ck72868_n1', 'ck72868_n1', 'Ukrain');
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `order`(`time`, name, email)
    VALUES (NOW(), :name, :email)");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);введите сюда код
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
$stmt->execute();

echo '1';
```

js

```
$(function(){
    $(".send-button").on('click', function(){
        let request = {
            "email": $("input[name='email']").val()
        }
        $.post('api.php', request, function(response){
            if(response == '1'){
                let email = $('input[name="email"]').val('')
            }
            else{
                alert("WRONG!!!")
            }
        })
    })
})
```

html конец кода

```
                </div>
          </section>
          
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: пароль не палили бы

Comment: где находится страница со скриптом и где находится api.php? я про урлы ( можно просто путь без домена)

Comment: Посмотри в инструментах разработчика в Хроме на вкладке Network куда запрос уходит, и уходит ли вообще

Comment: Почему ты решил, что форма на сервер не приходит?